# Proof that if $A_m$ are such that no more than $k$ of them intersect at a time, then $\sum{\mathbb{P}(A_m)} \leq k$

Tags: probability

I found this situation while reading a probability proof:

There is a sequence of events $\{A_m\}_{m=0}^\infty$ such that any given outcome $\omega$ apears in at most $k$ of them. That is, at most $k$ of them intersect at a time. It is known that $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{m=1}^\infty A_m) = 1$.

Now, from those facts, the author implies this inequality: $\sum_{m=1}^\infty{\mathbb{P}(A_m)} \leq k$

I guess this is a fair basic inequality, and I can "convince"  myself it is true via Venn diagrams. But I just cannot prove it. Every attempt I take ends with me just reestating Bonferroni inequalities or similar statements.

Am I missing something? I am reading this in the context of random walks recurrence, so I believe the books assumes these kind of statements are known ath this point and do not expect  to find a lead there.

Any help is greatly apreciated, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use indicator functions.  $\mathbb P(A) = \mathbb E[\mathbf 1_A]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any given outcome $\omega$ is in at most $k$ of the $A_m$, then we have the pointwise inequality
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}1_{A_m}\leq k$$
and then taking expectations yields
$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_m)\leq k$$

Comment: Thank you! I will accept the answer once the 10' passes and I am allowed to. A question: I can say that $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{m=1}^\infty1_{A_m}) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}(1_{A_m})$ because of Fubini,since everything is positive, right?

Comment: I would use the monotone convergence theorem, but I suppose Fubini/Tonelli works too.